# Different bases for a subspace generated by a set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say we have a set of vectors $A$, which is the basis for another vector space $B$. We let $a_1$ be any vector such that $a_1 \in A$. Now let's say we have a set $C_1 = \{ a_1 \}$. If $\dim(A) >1$, that means that there exists a vector $a_2 \in A$ for which we know that $a_2 \notin C_1$. But since $A$ is a basis (thus all its vectors are linearly independent), it means that $C_1$ can't generate $A$ because $C_1$ has a dimension of $1$.

(Assuming the above is all corect) I was wondering about formulation. Do you just say that $a_2$ is not in the span of $C_1$? How would you mathematically explain that $C_1$ cannot generate $A$ (which term would you use)? Or can you just say that $a_2$ is not in the vector space of $C_1$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct to say that $a_2 \notin \operatorname{span}(C_1)$ to mean that "a linear combination of the vectors in $C_1$ does not generate $a_2$." It is, however, not okay to say that $a_2$ is not in the vector space $C_1$, as $C_1$ is not a vector space (unless $a_1 = 0$ -- can you see why?).